# Let R and S be equivalence relations on the sets E and F respectively

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

1. Prove that the relation on $E\times F$ defined by $(x,y)\sim(x',y' )$ if and
   only if $xRx'$ and $ySy'$ is an equivalence relation, called the
   *product relation*.
2. If $[(x,y)]_\sim$ is the equivalence class of $(x,y)$
   under the product relation, prove that $[(x,y)]_\sim =[x]_R \times[y]_S$.
3. Find a bijection between $(E\times F)/\sim$ and $(E/R) \times (F/S)$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1.), this is just a matter of checking $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. For any $x \in E$ and $y \in F$, we know $xRx$ and $ySy$ since $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations. Hence, $(x,y) \sim (x,y)$, showing reflexivity. I'll leave it to you to check the other two properties.

A hint for 2.): it may be useful to write out the sets explicitly. E.g.
$$
[(x,y)]_\sim = \{ (x',y') \in E\times F : (x',y') \sim (x,y)\} = \{(x',y')\in E \times F : xRx', \; ySy'\}
$$
Notice you can re-write the last set as the product of two sets.....

For 3.), the answer is basically contained in 2.)

Comment: Let me suggest you take a look at our guidelines for [enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), by refraining from answering poorly written posts such as this one.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, and I will take it into account next time. I personally didn't think the post was *poorly written* since the question/problem is stated clearly. If anything, just missing context/effort from the OP, which is why I structured the "answer" as just giving some hints/basic guidance. @LeeMosher

Comment: Why is a poor question?